# Main menu is hidden from unauthenticated users

Tags: navigation

I am using a slightly modified Responsive Batrik theme. The odd thing is that the main manue and site logo are hidden from unauthenticated users. When they log in, they can see the menu and logo.

I'm wondering why this happen and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow Below things:

1) Make sure that in admin/people/permissions "View published content", "view own Unpublished Content are "Unchecked" for the "anonymous user".

2) Still if you are getting those "Disclaimer and Policies" menu links. i) Create a new menu and add those links in to that menu. While adding links Give the Parent menu link to "Main Menu". and save the menu. ii) Then admin/structure/block, configure the menu block: Give the permission to access only to Authenticated User and save the block

or,

If you are assigning main menu (as block) to region, you can control it's visibility by "Visibility settings". If you are rendering it in .tpl.php file then you can do it like this: Example (bartik's page.tpl.php):

```
<?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(

  'links' => $main_menu,

  'attributes' => array(

    'id' => 'main-menu-links',

    'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),

  ),

  'heading' => array(

    'text' => t('Main menu'),

    'level' => 'h2',

    'class' => array('element-invisible'),

  ),

)); ?>
```